# Animation from sub-component is not displayed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Problem :**
Animation is not played from the parent component.

**Context :**

I have two components.

**The first one (Parent component):**

```
export default function LevelSecondItem (props) {
    const { Data, moveTo, Identifiant, Score, GAME } = props;

    return (
        <View style={styles.main_container}>
          <ProgressBarLight 
            percentage={40} 
            total={3}
            items={1}
            label={Data.description}
          />
          <View style={styles.second_container}>
            <ButtonCustom text={"Commencer"} onPress={() => moveTo(Data.puzzle,Identifiant+"-"+Data.id,GAME) }/>
          </View>
        </View>
    )

}
```

**The second component (sub-component - child) :**

```
const ProgressBarLight = (props) => {
  const fadeAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current  // Initial value for opacity: 0

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(
      fadeAnim,
      {
        toValue: 100,
        duration: 10000,
        useNativeDriver:false
      }
    ).start();
  }, [fadeAnim])

  return (<Animated.View><Animated.Text>{fadeAnim}</Animated.Text></Animated.View>)
}
```

**Comment :**

When saving the file, react is updating the app. In this way, I'm able to see the animated value. The value is changing. But the main component is not showing the animation. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the animated value to zero by using `animation.setValue(0)` . I was not able to find this function...
I try to use `setAnimation(0)` and this is thowing an error.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Animated } from 'react-native'
import {GREY80_VALUE,GREEN_VALUE} from '../GlobalConstant'

export default function CardIndicator(props) {
    const { currentTotalIndex, currentTotalObject } = props;

    const [animation, setAnimation] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

    const anim = ()=>{
        Animated.timing(
            animation,
            {
              toValue: 1,
              duration: 1000,
              useNativeDriver: false,
            }
          ).start(()=>{
            Animated.timing(
                animation,
                {
                  toValue: 0,
                  duration: 1000,
                  useNativeDriver: false,
                }
              )
          });
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        animation.setValue(0)
        anim()
    },[currentTotalIndex])

    const boxInterpolation =  animation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange:[GREEN_VALUE , GREY80_VALUE]
    })

    const animatedStyle = {
        backgroundColor: boxInterpolation
    }

    return (<Animated.View style={{padding:10,borderRadius:5,...animatedStyle}}><Text style={{fontFamily:"RobotoMono-Bold",fontSize: 16}}>{currentTotalIndex+" / "+currentTotalObject}</Text></Animated.View>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [react native animatable](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable) library it's very easy to use
just like this

```
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
const FadeInView = (props) => {

  return (<View><Animatable.Text animation="fadeIn">{"your text here"}</Animatable.Text></View>)
}
```

you can find more props of this library and use it

Comment: Thank you to take time to reply. But your are not replying to the question. I don't get why the animation is not displayed in the parent component. The sub-component is working but the animation is not displayed in the parent component. The animation is working properly

Comment: in your code, you do not use fadeAnim value. firstly you are using `useRef` instead of `useState`. you need to replace `const fadeAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current ` to `const [fadeAnim, setFadeAnim] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))`

Comment: I got the same problem. (Good idea as usestate is updating the render by the way). The `fadeAnim` variable is use in the `<Animated.Text>{fadeAnim}</Animated.Text>` . thank you again . Trying to make a sort of chronometer animation

Comment: you are welcome . if you want to use animation in your code then you need to use `fadeAnim` value like this `<Animated.View style={{opacity:fadeAnim}}><Text>{fadeAnim}</Text></Animated.View>`

Comment: This is currently not working also. I don't have any kind of workaround. Why the parent is not showing the animation. What's is rendering this animation usually? I can't add a use effect to the parent component.

Comment: please goto this website and try to figure out with you code https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/react-native-animated-fade-in-fade-out-effect